# Difference in device FPS iphone 6 and iphone 5 Spritekit

Tags: iphone, sprite-kit, device, frame-rate

So i've found a lot of threads regarding the change in fps to 30 while testing on simulators inside the computer, but I haven't found any threads explaining why an iPhone 6 can run a game at 60fps but then an iPhone 5 runs the same game at 30fps. I am testing on actual devices not simulators and this problem is occuring. Im running into this issue while using Xcode 6 and SpriteKit. Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You need to be much more specific in what your issue is. Are you having a FPS lag in general, certain parts of your code...?

Comment: hm... what does it say for `CPU %` in the debug navigator when you run on an iPhone 5 vs iPhone 6?

Comment: sangony - The FPS on an iPhone 5 is being forced down to roughly 30fps. 31 to be exact. But on the iPhone 6 it is at 60fps. I even tried manually setting the skivew.frameInterval property to 1. 

M321k - The cpu on the iPhone 5 is 12% while on the iPhone 6 it is 16%

Comment: Does it look chopped up and laggy? I wouldn't be surprised if it is just mislabeled.

Comment: Nope doesn't look chopped up or laggy. The fix that I'm using currently to resolve differences across devices is setting the skivew.frameInterval property to 2. This makes all the devices 30fps. This way users experience the same amount of calls to the update function every second. Looks completely find at 30fps, just wish i could understand why it was being forced to 30.